# How come I cannot get this item marked as 'complete' (react to do list)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot get the completed property in the todo item object to change from false to true (in the `completeItem` handler function).

Essentially, when the user clicks on the checkbox, it fires the completeItem handler, where the id of the object is passed as an argument.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    input: "",
    todos: []
  };

  onChangeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmitHandler = () => {
    const toDos = [...this.state.todos];

    const id = toDos.length ? toDos[toDos.length - 1].id + 1 : 1;

    toDos.push({
      id,
      description: this.state.input,
      completed: false
    });

    this.setState({ todos: toDos, input: "" });
  };

  completeItem = (id, checked) => {
    let todos = [...this.state.todos];

    todos = todos.map((item, index) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const completed = !item.completed;

        console.log(completed);

        return {
          id: item.id,
          completed,
          description: item.description
        };
      }

      return item;
    });

    this.setState({ todos });

    console.log(this.state.todos);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <InputField
          change={this.onChangeHandler}
          submit={this.onSubmitHandler}
          input={this.state.input}
        />
        <ToDoList todos={this.state.todos} completeItem={this.completeItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am wanting to change the todo item's completed property to true.

Comment: your console.log will show the old todos, because setstate is async

Comment: Also, [**your current code works**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-p9mez). if you click the checkbox and it checks then you are setting it correctly